# Handeling hundres of thousands(300 000+) of MKAnnotations, how should i handle the storing?

Tags: iphone, database, mkannotation, mapkit

Saving these locations with the name of the locations(Title + latitude and longitude) in the app takes quite a lot of space. How can I reduce the size of the app? Any suggestions would make me greatful.

And also this will probably slow down the performance of the app, any suggestions considering that?

EDIT1:
It just hit me that if I save everything on an online server and query that for "tiles of annotations" just as google map does that might be the solution. So my question now is: Does anyone know a good algorithm for querying for "tiles of annotations"? This might be quite tricky since the map contains of several zoomLevels etc.
For starters, I will probably create several quadtrees(one for each zoomLevel) where I store which tiles that I already have queried for.

Do you guys think that this approach might be good? Or will it be too slow to run on 3G?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you storing them now? A .plist file and loaded into an NSArray or what?

Comment: Right now i store them in XMLformat in an file that I read and add all annotations at startup to an "offscreen-map"(A mapview with size maprectzero), which I use for loading annotations on and off screen for clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't set any limitations to the solution, here's what I would do;

First of all, store the annotations in a real database, 300k records is a bit much for an XML file, you will have to start querying them at some point and XML just isn't fit for that.

Second, I'd store it either on the device, or on a server. Your choice, I don't know how large 300.000 annotations are. I'd query the server, or the database, per region of a set radius. That shouldn't be too hard to do and it should limit the amount of queries (and thus server communication) nicely. You can directly couple that with the callbacks you get from `MKMapView` or your `CLLocationManager` instance.

If you are still worried about having too much communication, build in a caching mechanism. Temporarily store the result of the queries on disk for a set amount of time (or set amount of space, or how often they are used, whatever the purpose of your data is). Build the query mechanism so that it should try to resolve the result from disk first, before going to your database or server (well, if you have a local database you shouldn't need a real caching mechanism).

If you are not able to do any of those things (have a server, or a database) at least split up the XML file and make it easy for yourself to manage and query the data. Do lazy loading, but make sure your data structure is set up for lazy loading (XML sure isn't).

P.S: don't worry about zooming too much if you are querying; just query for the current location + an offset radius. Your offset radius would be defined by the amount of zooming, it would be just another parameter to send along to your server/database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that if I just store all the annotations on an server like you suggest and try to mimic the googlemaps behaviour, that I query it for "tiles".

Although I need clustering so annotations will be different on different zoomLevels. But just having several caches for several zoomlevels might solve this problem? Since if im at a zoomlevel where there is so many annotations that I want to make several clusters of around 1330annotations I'll just get a few clusters sent to me instead of several thousand annotations.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand you, but if you zoom all the way out, you are potentially querying for 300k annotations? Apart from the overhead that may cause, think about the usability issues this imposes, putting that many annotations on a map. I think you need to plan that out for yourself before implementing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably load these locations lazily (only retrieve what's needed) from a backed server, and not use the app itself as the storage engine.

Comment: The communication between the server and the iphone should be quite heavy if I do this dont you think? And do you know any good way to make sure that you never query the same area for objects more than once?

Comment: It just hit me that if I design an sqldatabase that works just like googlemaps in the meaning that: You query for "tiles" of annotations and just store which tiles you already queried for your idea might really be awesome! Now I just have to figure out a good way to do this since there are different zoomlevels etc. All the clustering has to happen on the server.